# Facebook login with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I use omniauth-facebook 1.4.1 with devise to login with facebook. There was error of

```
Could not authorize you from Facebook because "Csrf detected".
```

It seems people solve this problem by downgrade omniauth-facebook to 1.4.0. I tried it but now there is error

```
The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController.
```

I have the routes

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => :omniauth_callbacks}
```

and the omniauth_callbacks is in the controller directory:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def facebook
  # You need to implement the method below in your model
  @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)  

  if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
end
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I find the problem. In route.rb I have a line of code

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
```

in front of

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
```

which overwrite the method, so it lead to

```
The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController.
```

I commented the first line then it works.